# Regular Expressions Razor Pages ASP.NET core @"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z""'\s-]*$"?

Tags: string, asp.net-core, razor-pages, nsregularexpression

What does the `'\s-]*$"` at the end of `@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z""'\s-]*$"` stand for? Am I right saying it means no white space and numbers allowed? I understand the start of it, just the last bit is confusing me. And it is the same for `@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9""'\s-]*$"`
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything inside of square brackets is matching a character or set of characters.  So here.  I recommend using a tool like [Regexr](https://regexr.com/7movj) to help you narrow down how it works with whatever input you can provide it.

But I'll break down what this means.

```
^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z""'\s-]*$
```

First of all, `^` means "the beginning of the input string" and `$` means "the end of the input string" - So everything in between those characters is what is being matched

There are two character sets being matched

First is `[A-Z]+` which means "match any capital letter from A to Z" and then the `+` at the end means to match the previous set at least one time, but as many times as possible

Next is `[a-zA-Z""'\s-]*` which is another set that matches:

- `a-z` - any lowercase letters from a to z
- `A-Z` - any uppercase letter from A to Z
- `""` - any double quote mark. It appears twice here because it must be escaped by the same character in C#
- `'` - any single quote mark
- `\s` - any whitespace character like a space or a tab
- `-` - a hyphen/dash character

Finally the `*` at the end means "match the previous set zero or more times, as many times as possible

Comment: The `""` is an escape sequence for a literal `"` inside a string

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Are you sure?  On [regexr](https://regexr.com/7movj) it seems to indicate that both quote marks do the same thing

Comment: @ChrisBarr as a javascript regex literal you don't need to escape any quotes, but I assume this is a string in C# (given the tags), where you do need to escape them (the `@"..."` construct treats a backslash as a literal one, so you cannot use that to escape the " that is also used to delimit the string). Try removing the "duplicate" from https://regex101.com/r/bTgZps/1

Comment: Ah yes, good point I forgot which language this was running in. You are correct

Answer (score 0):

`@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z""'\s-]*$"`

- `^` - This symbol indicates the start of the string.
- `[A-Z]+` - This part matches one or more uppercase letters.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9""'\s-]*` - This part is used to match a sequence of
  characters that can include lowercase letters, uppercase letters,
  digits (0-9), double quotes (""), single quotes ('), whitespace
  characters ('\s' which includes spaces, tabs, etc.), and hyphens (-).
  The asterisk (*) means zero or more occurrences of any of these
  characters.
- `$` - This symbol indicates the end of the string.